# How to "run a keyword if tag="debug"" in suite setup in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I have a .robot file which has 5 test cases where i have defined tags fro each of them.
i.e 3 of the test cases has `[tags] debug` and two of the test cases has `[tags] preprod`

Now i have a suite setup and suite teardown where for those test cases which has tags debug will perform certain steps and for tag preprod doesnt not require same steps to be performed

For Ex :

```
*** Settings ***

Suite Setup         Run Keywords
...                 Connect To DB  AND
...                 Create An Employee

Suite Teardown      Run Keywords
...                 Delete DB entries  AND
...                 Disconnect From DB

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test1

TC2 
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test2

TC3 
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test3

TC4 
    [Tags]  preprod
    log to console  Test4

TC5 
    [Tags]  preprod
    log to console  Test4
```

Now TC4 and TC5 does not require to perform `Create An Employee` in suite setup and `Delete DB entries` in suite teardown

How to implement if the test case has a `tag=Debug` perform steps in suite setup and suite teardown

Comment: Suite setup is ran before any tests. One workaround might be to use different Test setup in debug and non-debug tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suite setup is run once before any of the tests start. It is impossible to have it do something different for each test.

If you want to perform some action for each test, you need to use a [test setup](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-setup-and-teardown). For example, here is a keyword that will log different strings if the test has a "Debug" or "preprod" tag:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup  Perform logging

*** Keywords ***
Perform logging
    run keyword if  'Debug' in $test_tags
    ...    log  this test has a debug tag
    run keyword if  'preprod' in $test_tags
    ...    log  this is preprod  WARN
```

Comment: Thanks @Bryan how about if i have multiple tags for each test?

Comment: @Ashu123: I don't know what you mean. This code works if you have multiple tags on a test. Notice how it uses `in` rather than `==`.

Comment: if i add two tags in the test say  ```[Tags]  Debug  preprod```
both the if conditions are executed instead only for Debug. the command i used was ``` robot -i Debug sample.robot```, prepod tag test is also getting executed

Comment: @Ashu123: yes, because that's how I defined it. You're free to put any logic you want in the keyword. The point is, you can use `Test Setup` to run a keyword at the start of every test. What you do in that keyword is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

In continuation with Bryan answer. You need to understand that a **Test Setup** defined in settings section will be applicable to all the test cases.

as a result for both **Debug** and **preprod** tags , you are getting the same Test setup executed.

In short, you want different test set
up based on Tags.

To achieve this you need to use custom keywords of same name i.e. **Test Setup** in the test cases where you intend to have specific tags.

Here is an example to do the same.

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup  log to console  parent test setup
*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Tags]  Debug
    log to console  Test1
    ${success} =  Run Keyword and Return Status  Submit The Job      #Code will not switch to next keyword untill this keyword return the satus as True or False
    log  ${success}
    wait until keyword succeeds  2x  200ms  Submit The Job     #This Kw will run the KW 2 times if  KW fails   while waiting 200ms after each result

TC2
    [Tags]  production
    [Setup]  Test Setup  #this is your custom KW, which will overwrite Test Setup
    log to console  Test1
    ${success} =  Run Keyword and Return Status  Submit The Job      #Code will not switch to next keyword untill this keyword return the satus as True or False
    log  ${success}
    wait until keyword succeeds  2x  200ms  Submit The Job     #This Kw will run the KW 2 times if  KW fails   while waiting 200ms after each result

*** Keywords ***
Submit The Job
    Sleep  10s
Test Setup
    log to console  child setup
```

Now coming to your last point , you can use **-e**   i.e exclude option in tags to run specific test case

so the command will be

```
robot -i "Debug" -e "production" sample_tc.robot
```

This will execute only first TC, i.e. TC1